# symfony v3.4 unable to guess autowiring

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony v3.4 is unable to guess the argument when using autowire feature.

> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfig": argument "$key" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

I have also explicitly defined the argument but it still does not work, The argument is of type `string` of length 136 characters.

```
services:
     app.myservice.config:
         class: AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfig
         public: true
         arguments: ["%app_key%"] #defined in parameter.yml

    app.myservice
         class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
         public: true
         arguments: ["@app.myservice.config"]
```

Which works absolutely fine I can see the expected results when I invoke the services.

However When I write AppExtension i get the above error:

```
app.twig.my_app_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\MyAppExtension
    arguments: [ "@app.myservice" ]
    tags:
       - { name: twig.extension }
```

so I defined explicitly the argument

```
app.myservice.config:
     class: AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfig
     public: true
     arguments: 
         $key:  "%app_key%" #defined in parameter.yml
```

it still does not work

This is how the MyServiceConfig Class looks like:

```
 class MyServiceConfig implements MyServiceConfigInterface {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $key;

   public function __construct($key){
    $this->key= $key;
 }
}
```

MyAppExtension Class:

```
/**
 * The MyAppExtension class
 */
 class MyAppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
  {
  /**
   * @var MyServiceConfigInterface $key
   */
  private $key;

  public function __construct(MyServiceConfigInterface $key){
    $this->key= $key;
  }
}
```

The solution provided [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23221) did not help either since i have my service.yml inside `app/config/services.yml`

Comment: Instead of app.twig.my_app_extension use AppBundle\Twig\MyAppExtension as the service id.  I think what is happening is that autowire's automatic service detection is picking up your class and trying to autowire it.

Comment: what if you try : `public function __construct(string $key)` ?

Comment: @Cerad and Sylvain Attoumani I tried with both the suggestion but it does not work.. However I have created a simple app that replicates the error.  [link to the project](https://github.com/gghhh456/autowrire)

Comment: Think about it.  Autowire is all about classes and class names.  It has no idea what to do about app.myservice.config and app.myservice Good job reducing your issue to a single repo.  Now make yet another new project and follow the examples in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got bored.  Update your app/config/services.yml file to:

```
#app.myservice.config:
AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfig:
#    public: true
    arguments:
        $key: "%key%"

#app.myservice:
#    class: AppBundle\Service\MyAppService
#    arguments: ["@app.myservice.config"]
#    public: true
```

Your TwigExtension typehints against MyAppServiceInterface.  So autowire looks in the container for a service with an id of MyAppServiceInterface.  It does not look at the class parameter at all.  Now in your case you have MyAppService implementing your interface and autowire is smart enough to recognize that there is one and only one implementation of your interface.

Be a bit more robust to explicitly alias your implementation to the interface to prevent problems if you ever decided to add another implementation.  Not strictly necessary in this case.

```
AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfig:
    { $key: "%key%" } # Just showing off here

AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfigInterface: '@AppBundle\Service\MyServiceConfig'
```

And one more unrelated thing: Don't call your twig extension class AppBundleExtension.  Seems like you are mixing up twig extensions with bundle extensions.  Two different concepts.  Does not really matter but it may be confusing down the line.